# linux - awk or sed or sort -filter text file eliminating some duplicates row based on rules

Tags: sorting, awk, sed

I have a file that contains a variable number of rows like:

```
  cn015 00:00:02  0   0.00  99.00
  cn015 00:00:02  1   0.00  99.00 
  cn015 01:00:01  0   0.00  99.00 
  cn015 01:00:01  1   0.00  99.00 
  cn015 01:00:02  0   0.00  99.00 
  cn015 01:00:02  1   0.00  99.00 
  cn015 02:00:01  0   0.00  99.00 
  cn015 02:00:01  1   0.00  99.00 
  cn017 11:00:01  0  24.41  74.59 
  cn017 11:00:01  1  24.90  74.10 
  cn017 11:00:02  0  95.96   3.04 
  cn017 11:00:02  1  96.04   2.96 
  cn017 12:00:01  0  30.34  68.66 
  cn017 12:00:01  1  31.24  67.76 
  cn017 12:00:02  0   0.00  99.00 
  cn017 12:00:02  1   0.00  99.00
```

- the first column is a text
- the second column is a time field
- the third is a number

I want to obtain a file like this:

```
  cn015 00:00:02  0   0.00  99.00 
  cn015 00:00:02  1   0.00  99.00 
  cn015 01:00:01  0   0.00  99.00 
  cn015 01:00:01  1   0.00  99.00 
  cn015 02:00:01  0   0.00  99.00 
  cn015 02:00:01  1   0.00  99.00 
  cn017 11:00:01  0  24.41  74.59 
  cn017 11:00:01  1  24.90  74.10 
  cn017 12:00:01  0  30.34  68.66 
  cn017 12:00:01  1  31.24  67.76
```

I would to have only the first rows of every hours for every cn (in this example, only

```
  cn015 00:00:02  0   0.00  99.00
  cn015 00:00:02  1   0.00  99.00
```

for cn015 at 00:00 )

I prefer an answer using `awk` but `sed` or `sort` would be acceptable.

Comment: A. Not clear what you mean by "only the first rows of every hours" given your sample required output below that.  B. Use the `{}` tool at the top-left of the edit box on highlighted text to keep code/data/errMsgs in correct format. C. You forgot to post your code. StackOverflow is about helping people fix their code. It's not a free coding service. Any code is better than no code at all. Good luck.

Comment: Are the input lines sorted at all? By first field? By first and second fields? By first three fields?

Comment: all the line are sorted by the first, second and third columns like the sample.

Comment: shellter: i don't have a code to share because there isn't . i want to use a simple script to filter the output. i could eliminate these rows using some cycle for but it is slow and not optimized because the text file contains 200.000 rows.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
  $ awk '{split($2,t,":")} !a[$1,t[1],$3]++' file

  cn015 00:00:02  0   0.00  99.00
  cn015 00:00:02  1   0.00  99.00
  cn015 01:00:01  0   0.00  99.00
  cn015 01:00:01  1   0.00  99.00
  cn015 02:00:01  0   0.00  99.00
  cn015 02:00:01  1   0.00  99.00
  cn017 11:00:01  0  24.41  74.59
  cn017 11:00:01  1  24.90  74.10
  cn017 12:00:01  0  30.34  68.66
  cn017 12:00:01  1  31.24  67.76
```

prints rows for unique first and third fields for each given hour.  That's my understanding from the question.